# Use a cosine function to model the alternating voltage?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Household electrical power in the US is provided in the form of alternating current. Typically voltage fluctuates smoothly between +155.6 volts and -155.6 volts. The voltage cycles 60 times per second. Us a cosine function to model the alternating voltage

Help!!
I have no idea how to do it

Answer (score 1):

We have a frequency of $60$ cycles per second. We know:

$$\omega = 2 \pi f = 2 \pi \times 60 = 120 \pi$$

We have a maximum voltage of $155.6$ volts.

This gives:

$$f(t) = 155.6 \cos(120 \pi t)~\mbox{Volts}$$

Now work backwards and define voltage, frequency, period.

A pictorial shows:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since it fluctuates between $155.6V$ and $-155.6$, we'll take that as our amplitude of our cosine wave. It gives us that 60 cycles happen in a second, so $1/60$ seconds is the the time for one period (T). If we take $t$ for seconds, we get

$$V(t) = 155.6 \cos \left ( 2\pi*60 t  \right ) $$